# Markov chain and dice

Tags: probability, markov-chains, dice

My question is regarding exercise 5a on page 7:
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~soshniko/135b/Mid1Sol.pdf

I can see why the probability is $i\over6$ for the maximum to stay the same at the next throw, that is that the dice shows the same or less as the previous maximum.

But I don't understand the second part, that there is a $1\over6$ chance that the new die is bigger than the previous maximum. Shouldn't it be $1-\frac16$, or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $P(j, i)$ means the probability for going form the highest roll $i$ to the highest roll $j$. This probability is $\frac{1}{6}$ for a specific $j$ with $j>i$, as you'd have to toll exactly that $j$. Also note that there are $6-i$ possible values for $j$ with $j>i$, so $1-\frac{i}{6}$ would be the probability for increasing the maximum roll in general where you don't care what the new value actually is.

Comment: To restate @PattuX's answer, you are correct that the probability of going higher is $1-\dfrac{i}{6}=\dfrac{6-i}{6}$, but there are $6-i$ possible higher values and the probability of each individual one is thus $\dfrac{\frac{6-i}{6}}{6-i}=\dfrac{1}{6}$

Comment: Great explanations, thanks :)